# How to use Substring in left outer join

Tags: sql, left-join

I tried to join these 2 tables with ALTERNATE_ID's using substring in left outer join but it doesn't work. Can someone suggest me how to do it.
Here Table1 is master table,

```
SELECT
tab1.USER_NAME,
tab2.ALTERNATE_ID as 'Contract_no'

FROM TABLE1 tab1

LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 tab2 ON Table2.ALTERNATE_ID = SUBSTRING(tab1.ALTERNATE_ID,0,CHARINDEX('/',tab1.ALTERNATE_ID)
```

TABLE1:

```
ALTERNATE_ID 100-0000053-001/0001
```

TABLE2

```
ALTERNATE_ID 100-0000053-001
```

Comment: Join on substring column? Is the table small else it's gonna be super slow.

Comment: You have to subtract 1 from the '/' position number.
Substring('100-0000053-001/0001', 1, CHARINDEX('/','100-0000053-001/0001')-1)

Comment: ```ON tab1.ALTERNATE_ID LIKE CONCAT(tab2.ALTERNATE_ID, '/%')```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @AntonGrig, I have used this in column  it works fine but in join it is not working
Substring('100-0000053-001/0001', 1, CHARINDEX('/','100-0000053-001/0001')-1)             is there any way to join these 2 tables ,as there are no other common columns between these 2 tables

Comment: @Raswitha I have published my complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use substring from first char to position of `\` `- 1`
But if you have to join based on part of column, then you should created index on the substring part.

```
SELECT
tab1.USER_NAME,
tab2.ALTERNATE_ID as 'Contract_no'
FROM TABLE1 tab1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 tab2 
ON Table2.ALTERNATE_ID 
= 
SUBSTRING(tab1.ALTERNATE_ID,1,CHARINDEX('/',tab1.ALTERNATE_ID-1)
```

Comment: I have tried this one but am getting error as invalid length parameter passed to the left or  substring function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **SUBSTRING_INDEX** to split the string like this:

```
SELECT tab1.USER_NAME, tab2.ALTERNATE_ID as 'Contract_no'
FROM TABLE1 tab1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 tab2 
ON Table2.ALTERNATE_ID = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tab1.ALTERNATE_ID, "/", 1);
```

Comment: Am using SQL server, is there any alternative for SUBSTRING_INDEX in SQL server

Comment: Sorry, i have not seen the Tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` in the following way:

```
SELECT
tab1.USER_NAME,
tab2.ALTERNATE_ID as 'Contract_no'
FROM TABLE1 tab1
OUTER APPLY (Select ALTERNATE_ID 
             From TABLE2 
             Where ALTERNATE_ID=SUBSTRING(tab1.ALTERNATE_ID,1,CHARINDEX('/',tab1.ALTERNATE_ID)-1)) As tab2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `PATINDEX`, then it's easy to get the position of the digit before the slash.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 
  ON t2.ALTERNATE_ID = LEFT(t1.ALTERNATE_ID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]/%', t1.ALTERNATE_ID))
```

Or looking at it differently, the one in Table1 is like the one in Table2

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 
  ON t1.ALTERNATE_ID LIKE t2.ALTERNATE_ID+'/%'
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45ac1d47a0cf5a9243d0d58e4f3fa59b)*